# How to get the public key of identity？

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, identity, public-key

```
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: appAdmin, enrollmentSecret: appAdminSecret });
const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(orgMSPID, enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
wallet.import(appAdmin, identity);
```

`enrollment.key.toBytes()` is private key. How can I get the corresponding public key?

Comment: Can you please try something like `enrollment.key.getPublicKey()` and see if that works!

Comment: You can get the public key from certificate.
enrollment.certificate contains the corresponding public key.

Answer (score 0):

You can find public key on certificate. You can easily parse that certificate to get the public key if you don't find any implemented functions on SDK.

https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-an-x-509-certificate/